# SailsJS: Manually upload a file without forms

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to upload a manually generated temporary file into my skipper-GridFS receiver. This is my code:

```
var blobAdapter = require('skipper-gridfs')({
                uri: uri
            });

var blobReceiver = blobAdapter.receive();

var readStream =  fs.createReadStream(newfile.path).pipe(blobReceiver);
```

After executing the script, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at /Users/me/Desktop/Entwicklung/soowtf-v2/files/node_modules/skipper-gridfs/index.js:225:31
at /Users/me/Desktop/Entwicklung/soowtf-v2/files/node_modules/skipper-gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:472:11
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a problem with the undefined "callbacks", if yes, how can I define them? I only know that the Sails author used this on a normal file upload:

```
req.file('video')
.on('error', function onError() { ... })
.on('finish', function onSuccess() { ... })
.pipe(receiving)
```

The code above works, but I don't want the sent file in my GridFS - I want to add the modified one from the first example.

Answer (score 0):

The `var blobadapter` is wrong.

You might want to try something like:

```
var blobAdapter  =  require('skipper-gridfs');
var blobReceiver =  blobAdapter.receive({
                        uri: uri
                    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work :( - I'll get an connection error, because he doesn't use the uri declared in the settings.